# Querying DocumentDB using a property other than Id

Tags: linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to query my documents in my DocumentDB database. I want to use LINQ to handle the DocumentDB query and want to query for facebookUsername field.

If I use the code below for querying the standard Id field, it works fine but when I try to do it using facebookUsername field, I get a compile error that reads

> "'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document' does not contain a definition
>   for 'facebookUsername' and no extension method 'facebookUsername'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Here's the code I'm currently using for querying by Id and this works. I just want to be able to query the facebookUsername field.

```
dynamic doc = (from f in client.CreateDocumentQuery(collection.DocumentsLink)
   where f.Id == myId.ToString()
   select f).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I modify my code to query by facebookUsername field?

Comment: Try changing it to return an `IOrderedQueryable<dynamic>`... `from f in client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(collection.DocumentsLink)`

Comment: I've never used IOrderedQueryable before. Could you please elaborate what it is and why it solves my problem? I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: All I really meant was try changing `client.CreateDocumentQuery(collection.DocumentsLink)` to `client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(collection.DocumentsLink)`. Without it you're dealing with a queryable of `Document`s which don't have dynamic properties.

Comment: I see. I changed the code to this:
dynamic doc = (from f in client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(collection.DocumentsLink)
where f.facebookUsername == myId.ToString()
select f).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

But I now get this error: "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation"

Comment: In that case, do you have a class that represents an item in the doc db collection (e.g., a class that includes a `facebookUsername` property)? For example, if you have a class called `User`, you should be able to use `client.CreateDocumentQuery<User>(collection.DocumentsLink)`

Comment: Yes, your suggestion works and I understand your point. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var families = from f in client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(colSelfLink)
           where f.Address.City != "NY"
           select f;
```

will give you a List where Family: { "Address" : {"City": "NY"} } }

if you don't have an object like Family, in my case, then you can't use Linq to evaluate queries on dynamic objects. You need to then use the SQL Query Grammar.

```
var families = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(colSelfLink. "SELECT * FROM c WHERE field=value").AsEnumnerable();
```

should work.